# How can I send message to a telegram bot using python?

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot

I'm looking for a way to send a message to a bot using another bot. I have API of these two bots.
The library that I am using is telebot, and with below codes I can send a message to channel or any accounts, but I don't know how can I get chat id of a bot.

```
bot = telebot.TeleBot(TOKEN)
bot.send_message(yourID, 'your_message')
```

Comment: If it's a one time thing, forward one of the first bot's messages to the second bot, save the chat ID inside the second bot (I think there was a way to store forwarded messages id) and you are good to go.

Comment: thanks I get my bot id, but I couldn't send bot to bot I get this error, telebot.apihelper.ApiTelegramException: A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 403. Description: Forbidden: bot can't send messages to bots

Answer (score 1):

It seems that there is not a specific way to do this and telegram is restricting bot-to-bot interactions for some reasons. However, you can use a neat trick.
You can create a dummy account as a sort of middle man for the interactions. Using the Telegram API (not to be confused with the Bot API) you can create an automatic message forwarding service for the dummy user just to forward the message from bot A to bot B. Hence creating the connection you want.
One such example of TelegramAPI is Telethon. Check [here](https://medium.com/@jiayu./automatic-replies-for-telegram-85075f28321) for an example of using the API. You can also check [here](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/) for Telethon documentation.

Comment: Thanks a million, Could you explain with an example?

Comment: I edited the answer and added an example of TelegramAPI which you can use.